# float is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition' Swift What is mirrordisposition?

Tags: swift

I got the following code:

```
let floatValue: Float = 1
let intValue: Int = 1

if floatValue == intValue   {
    println("Types and value are equal")
} else {
    println("Type is not equal.")
}
```

I know that it will print "Type is not equal."

But i got an error at `if floatValue == intValue`
The error is:

> Float is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'

I have never seen this error before and couldn't find anything about it.
This code does run fine in xCode 6 beta 1, 2 and 3.
I'm now running xCode 6 beta 4.

Does anyone know what this error means? And what I eventually can do about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`MirrorDisposition` is one of the types you can get from a `Mirror` of a value (using `reflect` function). They are made for the IDE to enable displaying the values.

```
/// How children of this value should be presented in the IDE.
enum MirrorDisposition {
    case Struct
    case Class
    case Enum
    case Tuple
    case Aggregate
    case IndexContainer
    case KeyContainer
    case MembershipContainer
    case Container
    case Optional
    case ObjCObject
}
```

The error message means that the compiler didn't find an `==` operator to compare a `Float` with an `Int`. However, it probably found an `==` operator for `MirrorDisposition` and `Int`, so it is trying to convert `Float` to `MirrorDisposition` but it obviously can't, so you get an error message.

(by the way, the type error you get is random, depending on the operator the compiler tries to use. I am getting `Float is not convertible to Selector`).

The error message is a bug, there should be a message saying `Could not find == operator for Float and Int`.

The obvious fix to check value equality is using a cast:

```
if intValue == Int(floatValue)  {
```

There is no reason to compare types this way because in Swift, types are checked by the compiler. There should never be a reason to check the type explicitly (speaking about value types, not object types, of course).