# Can't perform an IF statement on a UITableViewCell in Swift? Error: "is not convertible to MirrorDisposition"

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this? It's a simple if statement.

I get the error: 'NDTableViewCell' is not convertible to mirror disposition

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell:NDTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NDTableViewCell.identifier) as NDTableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) { // Error happens here!
        cell = NDTableViewCell.loadFromNib()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cell is not an Optional therefore it will never be nil. Try this instead, declaring cell as an NDTableViewCell? and then unwrapping it before the return.

```
var cell:NDTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NDTableViewCell.identifier) as? NDTableViewCell

if (cell == nil) { // Error happens here!
   cell = NDTableViewCell.loadFromNib()
}

return cell!
```

Also, see this answer for more details about the failed comparison: [float is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition' Swift What is mirrordisposition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891879/float-is-not-convertible-to-mirrordisposition-swift-what-is-mirrordisposition)

Comment: That answer breaks my heart. That does fix it though. But ho the horror... Thank you Eran.

Comment: Dunno if this is what horrifies you but you can make it slightly cleaner by dropping the type declaration on cell:
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NDTableViewCell.identifier) as? NDTableViewCell

Comment: That did it also! I might just need to go read about optionals with more attention.. so the horror goes away i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NDTableViewCell.identifier) as? NDTableViewCell {
   return cell
}

var cell = NDTableViewCell.loadFromNib()

//Configure cell

return cell
```